# Updating Multiple table using multiple procedures via multiple threads using same connection

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql

I have 4 tables
Each table is updated by 4 different procedures.
Each procedure is called by java using 4 different threads.
In each thread I am using same connection object(JDBC Datasource connection).
After all threads have updated all the tables, then I am committing the connection in java.
Data has been saved successfully.

Is this the right way to handle the transaction management using multithreading by sharing the same connection object?

Driver used: org.postgresql.Driver
postgres jar version: 42.2.2.jar
postgres server version: 10.6

Please provide your suggestions.

Regards,
Rakesh Kumar

Comment: In general you should avoid concurrent access to JDBC connection from multiple threads. You may find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217941/jdbc-transactions-in-multi-threaded-environment

Comment: Not possible. A single connection can only run a single statement at a time. You will either need 4 connections or serialize the access to the connection.

Comment: Why not to use connection pool so that each thread will have it's own database connection, especially if threads insert data which is independent?