# Clojure doing multiple DB queries at once

Tags: clojure, core.async

What will be the best way to implement multiple DB queries or any sync operation on a new thread?

Lets take for example the following code:

```
(let [res1 (mysql/query...)
      res2 (mysql/query...)
      res3 (mysql/query...)
      final (do-something res1 res2 res3)]
  (http/ok final))
```

In this example `res1` `res2` `res3` are not connected to each other.. meaning that you can execute all of them at the same time and then wait for all.

I would like that the 3 queries will go on the same time and then wait for all of them togehter.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is to use Clojure's built-in thread pool with [future](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) objects.

```
(let [res1 (future (mysql/query...))
      res2 (future (mysql/query...))
      res3 (future (mysql/query...))
      final (do-something @res1 @res2 @res3)]
  (http/ok final))
```

However, you will need to use separate Connection objects in the new threads because JDBC connections [are not meant to be shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217941/jdbc-transactions-in-multi-threaded-environment).